# Custom WCF binding for interacting with Oracle AQ?

Tags: oracle, wcf, binding, oracle-aq

Anyone aware of any good examples/resources using WCF to interact with Oracle AQ (Advanced Queueing), possibly even a custom binding?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To my mind WCF solves the same problems as OracleAQ can provide. WCF is tightly coupled by data contracts and can be bound to multiple transport types. OracleAQ is configurable by data contract (via registered XSD) or use a RAW xml queue. I am not aware of customer binding to differing transport mechanisms for OracleAQ and is very well documented and supported by ODAC. This wasn't the case for OO4O chatting to 9i but that's another story...

I would consider expending effort on implementing OracleAQ support within the client connection as this follows a similar overall pattern to WCF. Putting a service in between OracleAQ and the client endpoint to translate bindings doesn't appear to make sense other than introducing a level of complexity.